# JavaScript [object][Object] debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, object

I am asking this question because it is difficult to search/google it.

Sometimes in javascript, I want to debug things. I am writing `alert(var);` or `console.log(variable);` but very often I get something like this:

```
[object][Object]
```

If I don't know what object it is I have hard time guessing what properties it has. What are ways of painless debugging this type of objects? And by the way, what debugging methods do you recommend?

I know it is duplication, sorry for this. Answers I found so far were not satisfying.

---

**edit**

`myObj = {myObjProp: objVal}`

Ok. `alert(myObj);` => `[object][object]`. Is there a method that would allow me to alert a real object like `alert(exampleMethod(myObj));` => `{myObjProp: objVal}` ?

Comment: If you get that with console.log() then you are either not using it right or your data is already corrupted at that point.

Comment: try using [`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)

Comment: That's weird. If at all, you should get `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `alert` to print an `object`, then that `object` would be converted into a `primitive` value (`string`) before displaying. So for instance `toPrimitive({})` would be `[object Object]`. That is why you have to use `console.log(object)` while debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the debugger statement.
and access it from the console

```
function potentiallyBuggyCode() {
    debugger;
    // do potentially buggy stuff to examine, step through, etc.
}
```